# inline javascript in href

Tags: javascript, html

How can you do something like this:

```
<a href="some javascript statement that isn't a function call;" >myLink</a>
```

And have the js in the href execute when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:var hi = 3;" >myLink</a>
```

Now you can use `hi` anywhere to get `3`.

Answer (score 19):

Just put the JS code directly in there:

```
<a href="#" onclick="a=1;b=2; return false;">fsljk</a>
```

Though, you should not be doing inline scripting. You should unobtrusively attach event handlers.

```
<a id="lol" href="/blah">fdsj</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('lol').onclick=function() {
/* code */
};
</script>
```

Comment: would be cleaner with jQuery:  $('#lol').click(function(){  --do stuff -- });

Comment: This question is not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: many many items are not tagged completely...doesn't mean that a non-tagged element is not an option....

Comment: @bpeterson76: in this case, you should post your own answer separately, there is absolutely no problem with meder's code - except that I think the onclick function should also return false. If the OP didn't ask how to solve it with jQuery, why wouldn't a plain JS solution be as good as a jQuery solution would be?

Answer (score 0):

You can write inline-code in the same way as 
`<a href="javascript:[code]">`

This method is also available in other tags.

**addition**

if you want to Execution when something  tag clicking, you can fix with onClick attribute

`<a onClick="function()">`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had a similar challenge dynamically modifying the href attribute that sends an email when the anchor tag is clicked.

The solution I came up with is this:

```js
$('#mailLink,#loginMailLink,#sbMailLink').click(function () {
    this.setAttribute('href', "mailto:" + sessionStorage.administrator_mail_address + "?subject=CACS GNS Portal - Comments or Request For Access&amp;body=Hi");
});
```

```html
<a id="loginMailLink" href= "#" style="color:blue">CACS GNS Site Admin.</a>
```

I hope that helps.