# Issue with assigning onClick to link tag <a>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

Iam trying to assign a javascript function to a html link tag using this.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="doSomething()">link</a>
```

But what happens is the function doSomething is executed when I click the link second time. Nothing happens on the first click.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing inline scripting in the `href` and then also call a function in the `onclick` attribute. Do one or the other, or preferably, neither, and attach event handlers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519059/inline-javascript-in-href

Comment: Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/4umTf/ Problem may be localized in doSomething realization, or in other page's scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `doSomething()` function so that it does not cause the problem. (The problem does not occur if the function e.g. displays some text.) To get more specific help, you need to disclose more information.

Answer (score 1):

Seperate your JavaScript from your HTML by using [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener),

```
<a href="" id="myLink">link</a>

document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', doSomething, true);
```

and in `doSomething` remember to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) to stop the click from performing an action.

Comment: How is this answer related to mivaas19's problem?

Comment: Unless the error is in the _function_ `doSomething` as I removed the JavaScript from all attributes on the HTMLElement the unexpected behaviour should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

In my computer it works with the first click.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
alert("Hi :)");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="doSomething()">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Firefox.

Anyway, why use the href="javascript:;" then?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the doSomething() function here creates a MooTools dialog. Here is the code for that

```
function doSomething(tit,text,id) {

new mBox.Modal({
    content: unescape(text),
    setStyles: {content: {padding: '25px 15px', lineHeight: 25, height:'400px'}},
    title: unescape(tit),
    attach: id
});

}
```

May be this is what is causing the problem. But not really sure.